# Increasing performance with setting indices on fields used in a group by clause?

Tags: sql-server, database, performance, database-design, indexing

I create a view with many joins. I want to group the resultset by some of the fields I selected.

Does setting indices on these fields increases the performance of the query? I'm using MS SQL Server, but it should be nearly the same for all dbs, shouldn't it?

```
SELECT table1.field1, table1.field2, table2.field1
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.primkey = table2.tablekey
GROUP BY table1.field1, table1.field2, table2.field1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run a query with "Show Execution Plan" switched on, you can ask MS SQL server to suggest indices. It will indicate potential optimising indices to you by creating a hypothetical index on a column it thinks is holding things up and comparing that against your query.

Comment: This is an outstanding suggestion of lasting value to novices and veterans alike. It will work better once the database contains a non-trivial quantity of data. Be sure to update your database statistics using dbcc prior to using this advice.